# Why would someone do this?

Tags: java

Why would someone do this?

```
private Number genericObjectToNumber (Object obj)
{
    if (obj instanceof Byte)
    {
        return(new Byte((Byte) obj));
    }
    else if (obj instanceof Short)
    {
        return(new Short ((Short) obj));
    }
```

.....

```
    else if(obj instanceof BigInteger)
    {
        return(BigInteger.ZERO.add ((BigInteger) obj));
    }
    return(null); // if it isn't a number, we don't want it
}
```

Why not only return the cast?  Why go through the constructor of a new object?  Why not ask if obj instanceof

```
    if (obj instanceof Number)
    {
        return((Number)obj);
    }
```

Comment: There's no good reason, someone was just silly.

Comment: How in java would you distinguish whether an object was really a  `byte` or  really a `long`?  Is there anything like Reflection?

Comment: @ryanyuyu `byte`s and `long`s are not objects.

Comment: Just a guess but the syntax indicates the author was not an experienced Java developer. Especially wrapping the returned value in parentheses as if return was a method call looks very non-Java-esque.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think there is no valid reason to do this. It could make sense if the objects were mutable and you’d want to create copies of these objects. But the primitive wrapper classes are immutable, so calling the constructors using the existing objects doesn’t make sense.

Answer (score 2):

I think, the author was trying to make a generalized copy function.
The way it is works is like hes is trying to create a new object if this object is a number, returning a number in a new instance; e.g:

> Byte(byte value)
>   Constructs a newly allocated Byte object that represents the specified byte value.

probably, if it is to make sense, he might have lots of data and does not know if is a number or not while operating. as such he wants to operate just with numbers, or wants to use a common unit after and avoid exceptions if not numbers. I am not saying this the way to go on those cases, but it might make sense (as an explanation not a recommendation, sounds like a c++ program wrote the code). BTW, as noticed on other answers, the objects are immutable, so if this is a real example, there is not good reason for that.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense for several reasons:

1. Primitive types are immutable, there's no reason to go through the "new" constructor
2. It makes no sense to differentiate the different classes since the function returns a Number in the end
3. Even if differentiating and creating a new instance was necessary it would probably be better to write a generic method http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html (unless the code was written in some old version of java that didn't support generics), then replicating so much code (although it would compile-check for numbers which may not be desired)

The only plausible reason I could think is if the list does not contain all types of numbers and the programmer wants to white-list the supported types of numbers, but even then, the method is ill-named

Answer (score 0):

Because the original code is clearly meant to differentiate between different kinds of numbers. If you just returned "Number", then the obj would be casted to a Number (even if it wasn't actually a number) possibly resulting in a ClassCastException. By using the original code, the user is able to somewhat safely cast the obj to the proper type.

Comment: Number is a superclass for numeric datatypes.

Comment: Yes, but it takes any obj as a parameter; if you pass in cat, what will it return?

Comment: It will fail the `if (obj instanceof Number)` check

Comment: and not return anything, when it's clearly asking to return a Number

Comment: You could still use casts to achieve this behaviour (`if (o instanceof A) return (A) o;`). There is no need to create new objects.

Comment: And you could always keep the `return null` after the check like the original function.

Comment: Perhaps i'm misunderstanding the question here, but I'm also assuming that there are other instanceof x tests inside the "..." section of his question, which may not be primitive wrapper classes

Comment: If there were non-numerics, then yes you would still need the original option.  I just assumed that the OP meant only numerics were included.

Comment: It works like a charm with the `if ( obj instanceof Number )` provided that you have a `return null` for when the `if` failed. Best way is to actually write it and see.

Comment: `if (obj instanceof Number)` would take care of the `ClassCastException`. However, because Number is an abstract superclass, you would have to re-cast to a subclass to use any of the methods.

Comment: @mstbaum Sure, but the original version is also returning a `Number`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Good point; forgot about that.  Still good to keep in mind I think.

Comment: Re-cast would not be necessary if he was to operate using one of the xValue() functions, for some reason.